# Sending Parse push notifications to multiple applications from single application

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am wondering if it is possible to send push notifications to different IOS applications from only one IOS application via [Parse.com API](https://parse.com/). I can already send a push notification in same application but I want to send to different applications of mine, from a single application.

Comment: It is possible if the applications are set up under single application profile (have same api key), then you can have multiple apps for different platform and enjoy single push API.

Comment: but each application will receive different notifications. they wont receive same ones.

Comment: You can divide users into channels and then target users of different channels if you wish, so create channel for each platform (or other criteria for grouping) if you wish to send different messages. You can mix users from multiple apps in same channel without problem. Refer to documentation , they are describing these basic scenarios https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-platform/iOS

Comment: but how to assing same application ID and client key for different applications in Parse.com? I think this is not possible.

Comment: parse.com does not care how many applications run on same application ID and they in fact should - if you have android, iOS , windows app, you have 3 apps on the same application ID

Comment: it generates different application IDs by itself for different applications. So how to assign same application ID for different applications? (not devices)

Comment: you don't need to  generate them, you can resuse just one application from parse dashboard, using single applicationID in all platforms , differences are than handled through database if you need

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand. I am not talking about platforms. I am talking about different apps.

Comment: If you want to group notifications together you either share app in parse dashboard - then you can use most of SDK easily to target users you want,  or create cloudcode API in each project  and be sure to call them appropriate API yourself from the app or backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically use the REST API from Cloud Code, calling back in to Parse with different headers.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": YOUR_APP_ID,
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": REST_API_KEY,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: {
    "data": {
      "alert": "Yo"
    }
  },
  url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push"
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Successful push");
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Taken from official forums here: [Click here](https://www.parse.com/questions/push-to-local-timezone-from-cloud-code)

Comment: How can I integrate this code to xcode? I mean the sender application will be IOS App.

Comment: You would look at docs.parse.com for iOS and find the Cloud Functions section where you call a cloud function from iOS.  Use the Cloud Code guide to see about setting up this push request in a cloud function.