# parse push notifications to multiple ios applicatios from single parse application

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications

this is my first question on stackoverflow. I'm really in desperate. I intend to develop multiple applications and individually upload them to the store. However, the backend is the same, ie. I send push notifications to all ios apps from the same backend. I use parse to send notifications. Is possible to send notifications to different ios applications from parse?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant sections of your code you are using to parse notifications. Also: what do you mean by "backend"?

Comment: I use parse to send notifications. In my case, the backend is parse (parse.com). The code is not relevant, I think. To send notifications I have to certify the bundle(com.example.appname, for example). For each different app in the appstore I have a different bundle. What I try to do is send a notification to all the different apps from a single application of parse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Parse push notifications to multiple applications from single application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852045/sending-parse-push-notifications-to-multiple-applications-from-single-applicatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible according to this tutorial : [Click here](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications)

You will have to create and upload different .p12 certificates for each of your apps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed this tutorial but I did not realize that I can upload more than one certificate